# .Add/.Remove property not working C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm running into a lot of troubles, understanding and implementing List/ Array Lists in a school project. We are asked to use a method to do a basic task (such as add strings to a list("Bag") using methods given to us "insert" and "remove", instead of built in property for Lists, which I understood to be ".Add" and ".Remove") but it is not working, mainly because I don't understand the data structure. I could call "BoundedBag" b and c in the method but that would be messy and I would not be able to re use the code if a new instance of the List is created. I'm pretty stumped on a seemingly basic task. 
If someone has any tips as to how I could approach this, it would be very helpful.
thanks

```
 namespace A111111
 {
    class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BoundedBag<string> b = new BoundedBag<string>("ShoppingList", 10);
        b.insert("apple");
        b.insert("eggs");
        b.insert("milk");
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        //b.saveBag("C:/test/mybag.txt");
        BoundedBag<string> c = new BoundedBag<string>("ShoppingList", 10);
        //c.loadBag("C/test/mybag.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(c.remove());
        Console.WriteLine(c.remove());
        Console.WriteLine(c.remove());

    }


}
public interface Bag<T> where T : class
{
    T remove();
    void insert(T item);
    string getName();
    bool isEmpty();
}
public class BoundedBag<T> : Bag<T> where T : class
{
    private string bagName; // the name of the bag
    private int size; // max size of the bag
    private int lastIndex;
    private T[] items;
    private Random rnd;

    public static int Length { get; private set; }

    public BoundedBag(string name, int size)
    {
        bagName = name;
        this.size = size;
        rnd = new Random();
        items = new T[size];
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return bagName;
    }
    public bool isEmpty()
    {
        return lastIndex == -1;
    }
    public bool isFull()
    {


        if (items.Length  >= size)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else { return false;}
    }

    /*public T remove()
    {
        // fill in the code as directed below:
        // using rnd object remove a random item from items
        // and returns it
        // throw EmptyBagException if necessary
        items.Remove(rnd);
    }*/
    public void insert(T item)
    {
        // fill in the code as directed below:
        // insert item into items container
        // throws FullBagException if necessary
        items.Add(bagName,size);
    }


}
```

}

EDIT

hanks for your responses by properties I meant built in methods of arrays (my mistake). I commented the remove method for now so I could focus on the inserting method. Loading/saving the file is not my main concern, as I'm trying to take it step by step. Since I don't understand the basic structure of this program, I'm attempting to do the most basic thing, which is add contents to the "bag". At this point, I understand that "BoundedBag" is a child(?) of "Bag" and < T > is a type parameter. What I don't understand is how I can insert an item < string > let's say, into a BoundedBag object in the "insert" method as required. I tried

```
 items.Add(bagName,size);
```

as well as

```
  BoundedBag<T>.add;
```

so at this point I'm just throwing out attempts without understanding what I'm doing

Comment: You are not using the type "List". You have created an object with an array. Essentially you are making "List" by having an array and adding methods/functions to assist with managing the List. You should complete the remove() method so that you can remove random items from the BoundedBag.

Comment: Also. `Add`, `Remove`, `Insert`, `Clear` are *methods*, not properties.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Can you elaborate in your question what "mainly because I don't understand the data structure" means to you? I think doing so will reveal (and hopefully resolve) some gaps in your understanding of object oriented programming.

Comment: Array to not have an .Add method.  VTC

Answer (score 2):

B and C aren't same the object just because they happen to have the same properties.

B and C are separate instances.  They are at different locations in memory.

Since you haven't added any records to c, there's none to remove.

The code you commented out, its probably pretty important.  It looks like that's a mechanism to save the bag contents or load it from a source.  That's not happening, so c won't have records.